# NSFilSize is only returns 192 for any file path

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager, nsfilehandle

i tried with `attributesOfItemAtPath` of `NSFileManager` to get file size of previously saved video. it's only returning 192 always.

```
NSDictionary *assetDIct = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[assetUrl path] error:&err];
NSLog(@"file size %llu for file %@",assetDIct.fileSize,assetUrl.path);
```

i got zero by using `NSFileHandle`

```
unsigned long long fsize = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:[assetUrl path]] seekToEndOfFile];
NSLog(@"File size: %d", fsize);
```

The file path is

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4567DC4F-7F90-41BC-864E-D0FF2ECD9BA1/Library/com.apple.UserManagedAssets.sx8JGn/rajeev_653436252DF034A0.movpkg

Comment: try this `NSInteger fileSize=[assetDIct fileSize]; NSLog(@"getFileSize 
 == %ld",fileSize);
`

Comment: same value 192 i got for every file path

Comment: try this `unsigned long long getFileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[assetUrl path] error:nil][NSFileSize] unsignedLongLongValue];NSLog(@"getFileSize == %ld",fileSize);`

Comment: same again :( ...

Comment: what is the original size

Comment: try with diferent video once

Comment: 33.45 MB, 174.6MB, 96.3 MB, 68.7 MB are the sizes resply

Comment: try this `NSDictionary * assetDIct = [[assetUrl path] resourceValuesForKeys:@[NSURLFileSizeKey] error:nil];
    long long fileSize =  assetDIct.fileSize;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190419/discussion-between-code-cracker-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: `rajeev_653436252DF034A0.movpkg` is not a file but a folder. The movie data itself is burried somewhere in that fiolder.

Comment: thank you so much @Codo